# how to fix "$(__dirname)/src/" path does not exist in the 'gatsby-source-filesystem'

Tags: node.js, gatsby

I am new to gatsby. I went through the process of adding `gatsby-source-filesystem` to `gatsby-config.js` and I gave it the proper path to where my first test `.md` file is:

```
{
    resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
    options: {
        name: `src`,
        path: `$(__dirname)/src/posts`        
    }
}
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

> ```
> The path passed to gatsby-source-filesystem does not exist on your file system: `${__dirname}/src/`
> Please pick a path to an existing directory
> ```

Can somebody help me understand why this isn't working?

Comment: you probaby want `${__dirname}/src/posts`  not `$(__dirname)/src/posts`

Comment: The first uses brackets `${}`, the second one uses parentheses `$()`. Brackets expand inside template literals, parentheses do not

Comment: Thanks a lot..that was a stupid mistake@gman

Comment: We've all made that mistake 